# Web Api & Returning jquery Ajax Status code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So i'm trying to return and handle the statuscode.
Ok So I have a Web App, that does a Ajax call (calls a local method on the server)

like so

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "/Booking/Request/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { model: JSON.stringify(model) },
                cache: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                statusCode: {
                    201: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    501: function(data) {
                        alert('Opps an error occured.');
                    }
                },
                error: function(event) {
                    alert('Error' + event);
                }
            });
```

So the /Booking/Request/
 looks like so...

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Request(string model)
{
using (var booking = new HttpClient())
{
string addressRoute="https://api.remotelocation.com/Request";
booking.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = booking.PostAsync(addressRoute, new StringContent(model, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

It then calls a remote api

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostRequest(WebApi.Common.DomainObjects.BookingRequest request)
    {
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
//do stuff
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
    return response;
    }
```

however the following error is returned(500) which is not a 201.
[image]

Any Ideas in what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Status `500` in your web api code generally means you had an unhandled exception. In that case the framework returns 500 by default.

Comment: Debugging, this  line is hit response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
    return response; so struggeling to understand where 500 is coming from?

Comment: Did you make sure that the code breaks if any exception is thrown? These are the `Exception Settings`, in VS shortcut key `CTRL+ALT+E`. Check `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`

Comment: yeap, also ran it through PostMan and it returns a 201

Comment: Maybe something else in the `//do stuff` causes it like not awaiting the result of a Task (or calling .Result). It is hard to say without the code. If you do not think it is the code then remove everything you now show as `//do stuff` and try again.

Comment: check return response in debug see what is it in there

Comment: ok digging deeper (using fiddler) im getting "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending", i believe because its async its not waiting, any ideas how i rewrite to wait for a response (ive tried await, but seem to be having lots of issues)